# How to detect in a [HttpPost] handler method the view you came from?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Considering this example:

```
        public ViewResult View1()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ViewResult View2()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Processor(SomeModel model)
        {
            if (comeFromView1)
            {

            }
            //implementation
            return RedirectToAction("View3");
        }
```

Both View1 and View2 have inside a form that post to Processor.
How to detect inside it where did i come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to check Request.UrlReferrer. However, a user can easily spoof the referrer.

A better way would be an action filter which sets the previous action. Like this:

```
public class SavePreviousActionAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Session["PreviousAction"] = filterContext.RouteData["action"]
    }
}
```

Add this to all actions by registering it as a global filter (in Global.asax):

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new SavePreviousActionAttribute());
```

And then access it in your action:

```
if (Session["PreviousAction"].ToString() == "View1")
{
    // Came from view1
}
```